# Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment / Gray Background

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a strange problem with a map i'm trying to show. Sometimes it crashes, with the next error: "Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment" and sometimes it shows a gray background (like Google Maps's background) with the Google logo.
I've searched and tried a lot to solve the problem, without success.
Here is the code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.mMap = googleMap;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {

    }

    public interface OnMapFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onMapFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void updateMap(String latitude, String longitude){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude),Double.parseDouble(longitude)),15));
    }
}
```

And the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andrei.myapp.MapFragment">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace

Comment: I solve it, i didn't enable Google Maps API in Google API Console.

Comment: Try my answer. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `SupportMapFragment` from `Fragment` its best prectice ot Use `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` instead of `SupportMapFragment`

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

**Your `MapFragment` class as below:**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMap = mapView.getMap();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.1, -37.9), 10);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: getMap() is deprecated.